# How to add two objects of the same class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How do I override the + method in the class to add another object of the same class?

below is what I want to do but I'm sure my syntax is wrong

```
class Obj
  def initialize( value )
    @value = value 
  end

  def +( obj_to_add )
    @value +( obj_to_add.value )
  end
end

o1 = Obj.new( 1 )
o2 = Obj.new( 1 )

puts o1 + o2
```

Comment: Perhaps the fact that you're trying to use the exact operator (+) in the method that defines it?  That would seem kind of weird. What happens if you put the word super as the first line?

Comment: Add  `attr_accessor :value` and you're good to go. @MageeWorld, no, the `+` `in @value +( obj_to_add.value )` is defined in the class for which `@value` in an instance. In the example, `Fixnum`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland THanks for clearing that up

Comment: That worked, thanks Cary.

Comment: Also thanks for your help as well @MageeWorld

Comment: Just curious what use case this was for, @Pending? Also, @Cary Swoveland I would use simply `attr_reader :value` until we're actually writing over the value of `value` in another method. I think using `attr_accessor` when the writing part is not needed seems...wasteful. Not wrong, just not perfect.

Comment: It's for an assignment in my Ruby class @KaMok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem with the above code is that you don't have an accessor for `value` which you require in your implementation of `+`.

Also it would potentially make more sense to return a new instance of the same class:

```
class Obj
  attr_reader :value

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value 
  end

  def +(other)
    self.class.new(@value + other.value)
  end
end

Obj.new(1) + Obj.new(2)
#=> #<Obj:0x007fa9138e0d28 @value=3>
```